# Svg renders at a different pixel count than specified

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, viewport

I am trying to get exact pixel counts on an svg, but it seems off. I want it to be 300x56, but for some reason its rendering as 222x41
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3TKY.png)

But it seems like the pixels are inconsistent when I inspect:[It says 222x41 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwgOe.png)
[but 300x56 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS1Kw.png)

How is 222x41 calculated, and why does chrome debugger show both 300x56 and 222x41?

Comment: Please remove the height of the svg element. Since you are not preserving the aspect ratio (`width="100%" height="100%"`  for a `viewBox="0 0 1500 280"`), the position you are calculating may depend on the window size, hence the inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Explaining what you are seeing would require seeing more of the page.  We would need to see how the element containing the `<svg>` is styled.

But here's a quick explainer.

- The area of your page that the SVG is displayed in is called the "viewport".  The size of the viewport is determined by one of two things:

  - The `width` and `height` of the SVG *if they use explicit units - such as px*, or
  - The size of the SVGs parent container *if the SVG specifies percentage units*.

Your SVG has a `viewBox` this determines which area of the SVG canvas is displayed in the viewport.  The browser will scale the area of the viewBox up of down so it fits in the viewport.  Unless you turn it off, the contents will keep its aspect ratio

So since your SVG has a `viewBox` and its `width` and `height` are set to `"100%"`, the SVG viewport will be scaled to fit into the parent container **and** the SVG contents will be scaled to fit into that viewport.

You said you were trying to make the SVG be 300x56, but it looks like all you did to try and achieve that is set the `<rect>` to that size.  That is not enough because of the reasons stated above.  The effect of the viewport and the `viewBox` will be affecting the size that the rectangle is drawn at.

The `viewBox` of your SVG is 1500x280.  Your rectangle is occupying a small part of that - from (10,10) to (310,66).  Since your rectangle is being scaled down to 222.93x41.61, the SVG's parent container must be smaller than the viewBox. We can work out how big it must be:

```
1500 * (222.93/300)  ~=  1115 (if the width is constrained) or
 280 * ( 41.61/ 56)  ~=   208 (if the height is constrained).
```

If you want your SVG to be exactly 300x56 **always**, then what you probably want is to set the SVG's `width` and `height`, not the rectangle's.

```html
<svg width="300" height="56">
  <rect width="300" height="56" rx="4"/>
</svg>
```

Now the SVG will behave the same as if it was a 300x56 pixel PNG.